# Upgrading Cassandra from 2.2 to 3.0 in RHEL

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, cassandra-2.2

I have a RHEL 7.0 server running Cassandra 2.2.3 which I tried to upgrade to 3.0. When I run `yum update` it showed me there is a new version of Cassandra for update, and upgraded the server to 2.2.4-1, but not 3.0.

Now if I search yum for dsc30 I can find it, and presumably I can install it too, but why the automated upgrade doesn't happen from 2.2 to 3.0?

I've got a lot of data on my server and don't want to experiment on it. I had another test server which was running Ubuntu 14.04 and that one upgraded from 2.2 to 3.0 just fine, but on RHEL my server can't find upgrade to 3.0

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a different application and you can have 2.* and 3.* in parallel. Use

```
yum install dsc30
```

to install version 3.

If you want to upgrade your current installation then follow the steps described [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/upgrade/doc/upgrade/cassandra/upgradeCassandraDetails.html)

Comment: You are right, I could find 3.0 on yum, but what if I just want to update my 2.0 to 3.0 and keep my database as is?

That's how it works on Ubuntu/Debian. I have a Ubuntu server as my dev server, and I upgraded it to 3.0 just fine, but my deployment server is RHEL and remains 2.0, now I have to use two settings in these two servers!

Comment: Added the link to the upgrade documentation.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try the link soon. It's odd that there is a different model for different architectures.